# $(x+y)Γ(x+y)+(y+z)Γ(y+z)+(z+x)Γ(z+x)≥6$

Tags: calculus, inequality, gamma-function, jensen-inequality

If $x,y,z>0$ and $x+y+z=3$, prove:

$$(x+y)Γ(x+y)+(y+z)Γ(y+z)+(z+x)Γ(z+x)≥6$$

I tried convexity of $f(x)=\Gamma(x)$ and Jansen's inequality.
The  second part of the question asking if the following inequality hold when x,y and z are positive:
$$ \\(x+y)Γ(x+y)+(y+z)Γ(y+z)+(z+x)Γ(z+x)≥(x+y+z)Γ(x+y+z)$$

> Question is given by Jalil Hajimir

Comment: Why not use $z\Gamma(z)=\Gamma(z+1)$

Comment: Good point thanks.eems the second inequality holds too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathbf{\text{Hint: }}$

Use $\Gamma(z+1)=z\Gamma(z)$ and proceed with Jensen's inequality with the given condition that $$x+y+z=3$$